# reduce the time complexity for python for loop

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity, jupyter-notebook

I have python data frame with the following columns:

```
Index([u'Academic Period', u'Academic Period Desc', u'Student ID',
       u'Subject', u'Course Number', u'Course Reference Number',
       u'Course Identification', u'Schedule Type', u'Instructor's ID',
       u'Highest Degree', u'Highest Degree Code',
       u'Instructor Position Employee Group'],
      dtype='object')
```

I'm now trying to loop by rows, check and compare two column values:

```
for i in df['Student ID']:
    if df['Course Reference Number'] >= 50000:
        if df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 7:
            print df["Instructor's ID"]
    else:
        if df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 6:
            print df["Instructor's ID"]
```

I have 910,000+ rows in my file and it's taking too long to loop through.

Can i reduce the time complexity from O(n) to lower(with any possible algorithm)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really, no. To speed this process up you'd have to come up with an entirely new solution.

Comment: Why do you have `else` and then an `if` in the `else`, why not use an `elif`

Comment: He's printing out Instructor IDs based on Ref# and Degree code requirements.

Comment: BTW...your print line is the one taking up all the time.  If you were outputting to a file, it would actually not take as long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Course Reference Number':[10000, 10000, 20000, 30000,
                   50000, 70000, 80000, 80000, 90000],
                   "Highest Degree Code":[7,6,1,8,7,6,8,6,9],
                   "Instructor's ID":range(9)})
```

The df is:

```
   Course Reference Number  Highest Degree Code  Instructor's ID
0                    10000                    7                0
1                    10000                    6                1
2                    20000                    1                2
3                    30000                    8                3
4                    50000                    7                4
5                    70000                    6                5
6                    80000                    8                6
7                    80000                    6                7
8                    90000                    9                8
```

You can use boolean operations:

```
m_1 = df['Course Reference Number'] >= 50000
m_2 = df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 7
m_3 = df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 6
print df["Instructor's ID"][(m_1 & m_2) | ((~m_1) & m_3)].values
```

You'll get:

```
[1 2 4 5 7]
```

If you want the result rows:

```
print df[(m_1 & m_2) | ((~m_1) & m_3)]
```

You'll see:

```
   Course Reference Number  Highest Degree Code  Instructor's ID
1                    10000                    6                1
2                    20000                    1                2
4                    50000                    7                4
5                    70000                    6                5
7                    80000                    6                7
```

Comment: Not sure this works.  It prints the first or second character of Instructor's ID based on the criteria.

Comment: this is a super fast and very smart solution! But can i ask, if i want to print out the whole row in the dataframe for that specific instructor ID, how can i do that instead of df["Instructor's ID"][(m_1 & m_2) | ((~m_1) & m_3)].values ? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `df[(m_1 & m_2) | ((~m_1) & m_3)]`. I'll add this line to the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know python, however, you can reorder your conditionals to *potentially* be more efficient.

```
for i in df['Student ID']:
    if df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 7:
        if df['Course Reference Number'] >= 500000:
            print df["Instructor's ID"]
        elif df['Highest Degree Code'] <= 6:
            print df["Instructor's ID"]
```

I reordered it because, you do not want to print if the `Highest Degree Code` is > 7, **regardless** of the value of `Course Reference Number.` To me it seems more logical to check for something that determines whether you want to print at all first and then tree down to more conditions.

However, this method will only be more efficient if there are **more** occurrences where:

`Highest Degree Code is > 7`

than there are:

`Highest Degree Code <=7 AND Course Reference Number < 50000`